# How can a string be validated in Java?

Tags: java, string, validation

How can a string be validated in Java? I.e. only characters are allowed and not numbers? How about email validation?

Comment: You might look into Regular Expressions: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 13):

> how a string can be validated in java?

A common way to do that is by using a regex, or Regular Expression. In Java you can use the [`String.matches(String regex)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) method. With regexes we say you match a string against a *pattern* If a match is successful, `.matches()` returns true.

---

> only characters allowed and not numbers?

```
// You can use this pattern:
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";
if (str.matches(regex)) { 
    // ...
}
```

> email validation?

Email addresses have a [very complicated spec](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), which requires a monstrous regex to be accurate. This one is decent and short, but not exactly right:

```
String regex = "\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b";
if (str.matches(regex)) { 
    // ...
}
```

If you really want to look into it: [How to validate email](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and [Comparing email validating regexes](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) (PHP).

---

Here's an excellent resource to get started on regex:
[http://www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 5):

for string with only characters try

```
private boolean verifyLastName(String lname)
{
    lname = lname.trim();

    if(lname == null || lname.equals(""))
        return false;

    if(!lname.matches("[a-zA-Z]*"))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

for email validation try

```
private boolean verifyEmail(String email)
{
    email = email.trim();

    if(email == null || email.equals(""))
        return false;

    if(!email.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$"))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: There's really no point in checking for an empty string or trimming it because you can take care of those with regex.

Comment: the `trim` should be done AFTER the null check...or else you'll throw NullPointerException...

Answer (score 4):

For simple cases like that, go with RegExp as NullUserException already suggested. If you need more robust solution you can use some validation framework, i.e. [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/).

Answer (score 2):

If you have [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) as a project dependency (and that is quite usual), you can use [`StringUtils.isAlpha()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isAlpha%28java.lang.String%29). If you have a more specific validation or do not want a dependency on commons-lang, you can do it with regular expressions and [`String.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29).