# How to validate a string containing only some special characters is allowed in java?

Tags: java, string, oop

I want to validate a string in java. It should not allow any special characters, example @._ at dot underscore. Only these 3 characters should be allowed. No space is allowed. And only English alphabets allowed.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you could show us what you have tried so far :)
What website did you look at to solve the current problem? Try doing so for this post and your next one :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a string be validated in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732809/how-can-a-string-be-validated-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex (Regular Expressions):

```
public static boolean isValid(String s)
{
    return s.matches("[a-zA-Z@._]*");
}
```

Explanation:
`[a-zA-Z@._]`: Matches a single character that is either in the English
alphabet, or the three special characters '@', '.' and '_'.
*: Matches the previous expression between zero and unlimited times.

> Note: If empty strings are not valid either, use `[a-zA-Z@._]+` as the regex
> instead, or additionally test whether `s.isEmpty()` or has length of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're reading user input with a `Scanner` object, and can use the Character wrapper class methods. This is pretty much as easy to understand as it gets:

```java
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = stdin.nextLine();
boolean valid = true;
for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++){
  if(!Character.isDigit(ch) && !Character.isLetter(ch) && ch != '@' && ch !='_' && ch != '.'){
    valid = false;
    break;
  }
}
  // Code that deals with result.
```